# How to sort a List<T> by a property in the object, according to a comma separated string of the property

Tags: c#

I have a class called `Product` which has properties such as Id, Title, and Quantity.

Let's say I have the following.

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
products = getallProducts();
```

And, products have the following objects, in the following order.

```
Id, Title, Quantity
1, Product title 1, 5
2, Product title 2, 5
3, Product title 3, 5
4, Product title 4, 5
5, Product title 5, 5
6, Product title 6, 5
```

I have a comma separated string, which contains a list of Id. I want to sort my list of objects according to the values of `sortorder`.

```
string sortorder = '4,2,1'
```

After sorting, I want to achieve the following.

```
4, Product title 4, 5
2, Product title 2, 5
1, Product title 1, 5
3, Product title 3, 5
5, Product title 5, 5
6, Product title 6, 5
```

How can I do the above sorting, in C#?

Comment: Let's see an attempt

Comment: @Progman Does the suggested solves the issue when the sort list has a different size from the original one?

Comment: @AnastasiosMoraitis The `OrderBy()` expression/part can be adjusted to return `-1` or `list.Length` (depending on what you need) when the element to look for is not in the sort list. In fact, `IndexOf()` is already returning `-1` when the value is not present.

Comment: I see. Thanks. This can be reported as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution with `OrderBy`. But here what I have come up with.

First, scan `sortOrderList` and add the products that match the condition in the `sortedProducts` list(You can write re-write this part with LINQ if you like). Then, take all the products from the original list that don't exist in the new one, and add them as well.

```
IList<int> sortOrderList = sortOrder.Split(",").Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
var sortedProducts = new List<Product>();
            
foreach (var id in sortOrderList)
{
    sortedProducts.Add(products.First(p => p.Id == id));
}
            
sortedProducts.AddRange(products.Where(p => sortedProducts.Exists(sp => sp.Id == p.Id) == false));
```

Don't forget to add support for sort order IDs that don't exist in the original list. IE you should skip those.

Comment: I used this solution. But I think there is a typo in the answer. I corrected to the following:
IList<int> sortOrderList = sortOrder.Split(',').Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToList();

Comment: Thanks, @JK. There is no typo as `Parse` is a function, but I forgot to add `using static System.Int32;` here. It's better to insert the full qualification here `Int32.Parse`. You don't have to write the full thing. You only need to pass a function.

Comment: Please mark it as the accepted one, provided that you used it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think `List<T>` can be sorted automatically by hair search. To do this, I have prepared a piece of code for you below
The following code implements the desired answer

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
products = getallProducts();

List<Product> temp1 = new List<Product>();
List<Product> temp2 = new List<Product>();
string sortorder = "4,2,1";
string[] searchItems = sortorder.Split(',');
foreach (var item in products)
{
   var findItem = searchItems.Where(a => a == item.Id.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
   if (findItem != null)
   {
      temp1.Add(item);
   }
   else
   {
      temp2.Add(item);
   }
}

products = new List<Product>();
products.AddRange(temp1);
products.AddRange(temp2);
```

or this code:

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
products = getallProducts();
string sortorder = "4,2,1";
var searchItems = sortorder.Split(',').Select(a => int.Parse(a)).ToList();
for (int i = searchItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   products = products.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id == searchItems[i]).ToList();
}

public List<Product> getallProducts()
{
   List<Product> lst = new List<Product>();
   for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
   {
      Product p = new Product();
      p.Id = i;
      p.Title = "Product title " + i;
      p.Quantity = 5;
      lst.Add(p);
   }
   return lst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation for the problem with linq.

```cs
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

products = GetAllProducts();

string sortOrder = "4,2,1";

List<int> prio = sortOrder.Split(',').Select(i => int.Parse(i)).ToList();

var ordered = products.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id == prio.First());

foreach(var additional in prio.Skip(1))
{
    ordered = ordered.ThenByDescending(i => i.Id == additional);
}
```